# What is purpose assigning an error message to req.session.error?

Tags: javascript, express, authentication

In the [express auth example](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/auth/index.js#L118), an error message is assigned to `req.session.error` in the case of authentication failure.

I assume its purpose is to inform the http client but I understood the request object comes from the client. Why is the message assigned there instead of the response object?

Comment: **that** request object is **the** HTTP request object. If the authentication fails, you have the error in the request.session and then use the response object to redirect the user. Clear?

Comment: @rags2riches sorry I don't get it. How would the http client know the authentication error has occurred if the message is assigned `req.session.error`? I triggered the error from the browser but I could not find the message in the response.

Comment: If you want to use the error in your response, you need to access it in the request.session (in the example the user just assign a new error property to the object with a string type, the error) but never return the error back to the client. He just redirects it. Clear now ?

Comment: @rags2riches why would I need to access the error in `req.session` instead of directly assigning it to `res.session`? You say the auth example never returns the error back to the client but do you agree that message text is clearly intended for the client?

Comment: In that example, the error property assigned to the request session object is for the server only. It is never returned to the client because of the redirect to the login page. The error is not attached to the response object at all. You have a point and you are right in asking yourself "how do we warn the user?" Well, in that example you do not, because the user is only redirected to the login page. Do you need to send the error back to the user ?

Comment: @rags2riches if sessions are normally used to store user details, what is the normal way to return an authentication error message to the client? `res.send()`?

Answer (score 1):

The package you are linking to, does not return an authentication error back to the client. The only mechanism used to **display** the error (or success) to the client is the application level middleware that assigns a success or error message to `response.local` so that the `template engine` can display the error or the success message.

I believe this this the code that caused the confusion:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var err = req.session.error;
  var msg = req.session.success;
  delete req.session.error;
  delete req.session.success;
  res.locals.message = '';
  if (err) res.locals.message = '<p class="msg error">' + err + '</p>';
  if (msg) res.locals.message = '<p class="msg success">' + msg + '</p>';
  next();
});
```

This is an [application level middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application) that gets called for each request. What this middleware does for each request is to initialise two local variables for error and success that are copies of the request session error and success properties, respectively. It then deletes these two properties from the session object, and resets the response.local.message to an empty string. If err is true, it sets the response local message to a string representing the HTML that displays the err. Otherwise, is sets the success property to an HTML elem that the `template engine` displays as success to the client.

This does **not** mean the auth error is returned to the user. The user is **redirected** to the login page and if you test this on your own, you will see - in your dev network tab - a status code equal to the redirect (3xx).

If you want to return the error back to the client, you need to return a status code of 401 (client not authenticated) and **render**, not redirect to, the login page with the error displayed.

Comment: I see now that it [does](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/auth/index.js#L34) eventually return the authentication error to the client. My confusion was assuming `req.session` was specific to the request when in fact it is [used to store and access the session data](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession)

Comment: OK, The first link it's an app level middleware that assigns the `res.locals.message` to a success or error **html element**. This elem is then used by the `template engine` which displays it to the client. It does **not** return the authentication error (e.g. 401) to the user because the user is redirected to the login page. Test this on your own and look at the response headers in the dev network tab; you will see a status code that is 3xx, not 401. There is a difference between returning the auth error to the client (401) and redirecting the user (3xx) with an html elem displaying the err.

Comment: the second link is just a counter for views. See edited answer.